# How to deal with files recorded using Xamarin Android MediaRecorder

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using the following sample from Xamarin website, for Audio recording

http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/record_audio/

The recording is working well, and playing well on the device.

I am sending the recorded audio file to the server.

What are the best practices to decode files recorded on Android ?

I am trying to convert the uploaded recorded audio file,

From AMR file to MP3 or Wav or PCM

So far no luck,

Any help or direction appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I solved it, the file encoding and header was altered when save on the server, that is why it was marked invalid by AMR players or decoders.

Comment: This is for the Android Xamarin API.